# ksop2 java.io.IOException: Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: android, web-services

Hello stackoveflow team,

I got a strange error. I use ksop2 to make a soap call to http://www.webserviceX.NET. When I use an avm or a smartphone with android 2.3.3, following code works perfectly. When I run this code on an android smartphone with version 4, I receive this error:

E/ActivityRecord(212): sendActivityPerformanceInfo exception occurs: java.io.IOException: Transport endpoint is not connected

Here's the code:

```
  soapObject = new SoapObject(namespace, "GetCitiesByCountry");
  soapObject.addProperty("CountryName", countryIn); 
  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);
  envelope.bodyOut = soapObject;
  envelope.dotNet = true;
  httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE("http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx");
  httpTransportSE.debug = true;
  Log.d(TAG, "********** http - Call ***********");
  httpTransportSE.call("http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry", envelope);
```

The error occured at httpTransportSE.call(..)
Maybe you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have checked all these steps (and for some reason many of them are not returning a corect exception name)

- You have an active connection.
- You have Internet permissions.
- The code used for 2.x terminals is the same as that used by the 4.x terminals.
- You lately tested your service link type with an application as soapUI or with other terminals.
- You is sure that your code is currently running correctly on other terminals.

I not have no choice but to conclude that you are trying to establish a connection from the main thread, thus generating an exception of type [**NetworkOnMainThreadException**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) added since API 11 (3.0)

The solution to this is that you must run your call from a second thread and get the result with some kind of strategy as "observer"

*This is a sample code, if you want to implement this methodology*

***SOAP connector class***

```
 public class SOAPConnector extends Observable  {

    private static boolean isRunAction=false;   

    private static String ACTION = "";  
    private static String METHOD_NAME = ""; 
    private static String NAMESPACE = "";
    private static String URL_hprotocol = "";
    private static String URL_host = "";
    private static String URL_service = ""; 
    private static String outData = ""; 
    private static String inData = "";

    private final static int HTTPS_PORT = 443;
    private final static int HTTPS_TIMEOUT = 5000;

    private static boolean isHttps=false;    

    public SOAPConnector(String action, 
                     String method, 
                     String namespace, 
                     String hprotocol, 
                     String host,
                     String service){
        if(!isRunAction){
            ACTION = action;  
                METHOD_NAME = method; 
                NAMESPACE = namespace;
                URL_hprotocol = hprotocol;
                URL_host = host;
            URL_service = service;
        }

     }

    public void sendSoapData(String data,boolean https){
        if(!isRunAction){           
            isHttps = https;        
            outData = data;        
            Thread threadsoap = new Thread(runSendSoap);
            threadsoap.start();
        }
    }


    private Runnable runSendSoap = new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
            launchSendSOAP();
            handlerSendSOAP.sendEmptyMessage(0);
         }
         private Handler handlerSendSOAP = new Handler() {              
             public void handleMessage(Message msg) {}
        };         

    };

    private void launchSendSOAP(){
           isRunAction=true;
           try {
                SoapObject client = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);              
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                String tmpDate = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));                              
                String tmpData = outData;                                               
                client.addProperty("dataFIELD",(String)tmpData);                
                client.addProperty("dateFIELD",(String)tmpDate);
                client.addProperty("codeFIELD","NULL");             
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
                envelope.dotNet=false;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(client);               
               if(isHttps){
                  HttpsTransportSE androidHttpsTransport = new HttpsTransportSE(URL_host, HTTPS_PORT, URL_service,HTTPS_TIMEOUT);
                  androidHttpsTransport.call(ACTION,envelope);
               }else{
                  HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_hprotocol+URL_host+URL_service);
                  androidHttpTransport.call(ACTION,envelope);
               }                 
               Object result = envelope.getResponse();
               inData=result.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               inData="ERROR";
            }         
           isRunAction=false;
           setChanged();
           notifyObservers(inData);

   }
}
```

***Activity Call***

```
private SOAPConnector soapConnector = null;
private ConnectorObserver conObserver =null;
private boolean isActionSoap=false;

private void setServiceObserver(){
    soapConnector =  new SOAPConnector(SOAP_ACTION_dummy,
                                       METHOD_NAME_dummy,
                                       NAMESPACE_dummy,
                                       URL_hprotocol,
                                       URL_host,
                                       URL_service);        
}   

private void soapSendProcess(){
    if(!isActionSoap){
        isActionSoap=true;          
        if(soapConnector==null){
            setServiceObserver();
        }
        conObserver = new ConnectorObserver();
        soapConnector.deleteObservers();                    
        soapConnector.addObserver((Observer)conObserver);
        soapConnector.sendSoapData("TEST",false);
    }


public class ConnectorObserver implements Observer{
    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data){
        String resultData = (String)data;
        if(resultData.equals("ERROR")){
             //TODO fail action
        }else{      
             //TODO parsing action
        }
        soapConnector.deleteObservers();
        isActionSoap=false;

    }
}
```

> **This code has been tested with 2.2 ~ 4.03 Terminals
>  and with ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-RC.4-with-dependencies.jar library.**

Comment: dear RTOSKit, I checked all your suggested steps. I accept your advice and sourced out the SOAP call in a new thread. I have tested my code on Android 4 with different hardware (S3, samsung tablet, Huwei Ascent) and the error occured. I have tested the same code with a Galaxy Ace and other phones running android 2 and it worked. Ok, so I have set up an avm with android 2.3 (API Level 10) and tested the code => it works. Then I have set up an avm with android 4.2 (API Level 17) and my program crashes. I suppose strongly, the problem is the android version. Any further suggestions? Best regards

Comment: Well, yesterday before posting the code (as I always do) I tested code with  4.0.3 terminals and 2.2 terminals, and the same code is running on many more terminals and rule out a problem with the API, but is likely to you are using an older version of ksoap. that causes the disconnect from its endpoint, the version with which I have done this testing is:
ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-RC.4-with-dependencies.jar.Regards.

Comment: Dear RTOSKit, I solved my problem. You're right. I must invoke the soap call in a new thread and then show the result on the UI-Thread again with the method runOnUiThread(). Thank you very mutch for your efforts, it was a great help for me.